# ¿Cómo hacer que mi Api rest @PutMapping reciba un Body de angular y que realice un update en varios id?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, microservices

Actualmente tengo un servicio que recibe tres parámetros y realiza el Update sin problema al recibir datos de un front con Angular, los datos que guardo son de los campos una tabla modificable pero lo hace solamente por fila, con un solo id

este es mi metodo en el controller, con mi service y mi query

```
@PutMapping("/{cveEstado}/{comentario}/{idControl}")
    private void actualizaDatos(@PathVariable("cveEstado") String cveEstado, @PathVariable("comentario") String comentario,
            @PathVariable("idControl") String idControl){
        controlService.actualizar(cveEstado, comentario, idControl);
        
    }
```

service y query

```
    @Override
    public void actualizar(String cveEstado, String comentario, String idControl) {
        
        repository.actualizarCampos(cveEstado, comentario, idControl);
    }

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE CONTROL C SET CVEESTADO=?1, COMENTARIO=?2 WHERE C.IDCONTROL=?3", 
            nativeQuery = true)
    void actualizarCampos(String cveEstado, String comentario, String idControl);
```

y el service.ts de Angular esta asi

```
updateCampos(control: Control){
    return this.httpClient.put<Control>(this.baseUrl+"/"+control.cveEstado+"/"+control.comentario+"/"+control.idControl,control);
  }
```

Pero ahora cambie la lógica de mi front con angular, ya que guarda los datos de la tabla de cualquiera de las filas donde se haga una modificacion con su respectivo id

este es mi ejemplo de mi tabla, con los datos que almacena

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi nuevo servicio en Angular queda de esta forma,

```
//servicio nuevo
  updateControl(body: any): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      "Content-Type",
      "application/json"
    );

    return this.httpClient
      .put<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/control`, body, {
        headers: headers,
      })
  }
```

pero lo que no sé, es cómo hacer que el servicio en Java reciba lo de Angular, que lógica se usa para que pueda recibir los datos y pueda hacer el update en cualquiera de los id donde se haya hecho los cambios
alguien podría ayudarme por favor